# Как отформатировать абзацы по слову, находящемуся в где-то в тексте?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Помогите выполнить 2 пункт задания, т.к. 1 пункт, вроде, выполнен(код ниже).

Задание:

Написать макрос (компьютер) форматирования текста по следующим критериям:

1. Выделить все слова в тексте, начинающиеся с заданных символов (например: «компьютер») красным курсивом.
2. Те абзацы, в которых встретились эти слова, отформатировать следующим образом: отступ – 1,6 см; межстрочный интервал – одинарный.

```
Sub Task()
Dim s
  With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    For Each s In Split("компьютер")
      .Execute s, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Криво-косо, зато работает как надо.

```
    Sub Task()
    Dim s
      With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
        .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        For Each s In Split("компьютер")
          .Execute s, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
      End With

    Dim p As Paragraphs, f As Find
    Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

    For i = 1 To p.Count
      Set f = p(i).Range.Find
      f.Text = "компьютер"
      If f.Execute Then p(i).Range.Select

        With Selection.ParagraphFormat
          .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
          .FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(1.6)
        End With

    Next i
    End Sub
```